# org.osgi.service.application.ApplicationException: No application id has been found

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2011-09-13 10:30:39.110
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
org.osgi.service.application.ApplicationException: No application id has been found.
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.startDefaultApp(EclipseAppContainer.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.MainApplicationLauncher.run(MainApplicationLauncher.java:29)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:575)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1408)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1384)
```

Comment: The reason for this problem is almost always unresolved dependencies. So carefully inspect your target platform, your workspace and your runtime using the OSGi console (launch it with -console option).

Answer (score 4):

Could be dependencies issue; Goto "**Run->Run Configurations...**", Select "**Plug-ins**" tab and click the "**Add Reuired Plugin**" button

Comment: This should be posted as comment not answer.

Answer (score 2):

I've had a similar problem. I found that starting with -clean solved it in my case:

```
# ./eclipse -clean
```

I am running 3.6.1 on Ubuntu Lucid 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

Its difficult to say with the description given, you would have to double check your dependencies, if you've added some recently try to check your dependencies definition on product, feature and separate plugin's xml. Check [this](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t97082.html) website too.

Comment: In plugin.xml file I am seeing validation error:
Unknown extension point: 'org.eclipse.core.resources.natures' plugin.xml /CTSView line 76 Plug-in Problem

Answer (score 0):

If you see this when trying to start **OSGI console**, add this parameter to the command line (just after 'java'):

```
-Declipse.ignoreApp=true
```

or this line into your 'config.ini' file:

```
eclipse.ignoreApp=true
```